# How do I update a 2d array to convert grades to their GPA values?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a 2d array that holds students grades for several courses. I would like to be able to convert the grades to their GPA counterpart, assuming A = 4.0 B = 3.0 and C = 2.0 however I am not sure how to iterate through the array and update it to these new values. Here is what the array looks like

`int Students[3][5] =  {{88,97,79,86,94},{86,91,78,78,84},{84,73,77,82,89}};`

Comment: For those of us who aren't American, could you explain how to convert an average grade to GPA?

Comment: @mureinik I am assuming that for the conversion 100 - 90 = 4.0, 89 - 80 = 3.0 79-70 = 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what is going to be converted, but with a two nested loop you can do this, for example

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++){
    for(int j = 0 ; j < 5 ; j++){
        Students[i][j] = ......
    }
}
```

this is how you can iterate all items.

Comment: Thank you, I had this code before but never thought to just add if-else statements to convert the grades!